# Is it common for Buddhists in eastern countries to be close-minded and lacking in diversity?

Tags: personal-practice, lay-buddhism, metta

I have noticed a definite tendency for Buddhists east of Great Britain to be very narrow-minded and conservative compared to those further west. The same effect is noticeable in the United States among the extreme Protestant affiliations of Christianity in the deep south and I wonder if the origins have similarities.

Is this typical? Do all lineages share similar conservative and non-diverse views? I have seen a few Chinese Buddhists and they seem much more open minded. Wondering if this is a geographical thing or political or just a difference in Buddhist schools of thought.

Please advise.

Comment: I have visited monastic Buddhist communities in Thailand, Vietnam, Tibet, and Nepal as well as France, Great Britain, and the United States. I actually lived in the Kopan monastery in Kathmandu as a visitor for a period as well. So yes I have traveled to many Buddhist communities east of Great Britain. I ask this question as I search for a Buddhist community that will not call me names or regard anyone as a heretic who does not believe exactly as they do.

Comment: On the subject of people who "call me names", I hope you may find this helpful: [Akkosa Sutta: Insult](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn07/sn07.002.budd.html)

Comment: it is helpful. thank you. I tend to follow the advice given in the brihadaranyaka upanishad as well as TS Eliot's The Wasteland - damyata, datta, dayadhvam. self control, give of yourself, and compassion. I am trying to isolate the cause of their demeanor so I can understand it and avoid it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> "Is it common for Buddhists in Eastern Countries...lacking in
>   diversity.. ... ... The same effect is noticeable in the United States
>   among the extreme Protestant affiliations of Christianity in the deep
>   south"

Huh??!! Only Eastern Buddhists and Protestants in the American South?

Have you looked around "Western" Buddhist Centers in North America?

Here is an [article about the overwhelming whiteness](https://www.lionsroar.com/road-to-diversity/) of American Buddhist Centers

Here is one about the decades-late recogni[tion](https://www.lionsroar.com/diversity-in-buddhism/amp/) of it and some attempts finally being made to rectify...

A [report at pluralism.org](http://pluralism.org/research-report/racial-diversity-and-buddhism-in-the-u-s/) which says

"People of color are negotiating spaces within predominantly European American sanghas (Buddhist communities)."

I guess problems are easily seen everywhere except in one's own backyard.

Comment: I have seen limited diversity in local Buddhist groups ... but mostly from a lack of acceptance of Buddhism. The sangha here are mostly vietnamese or korean or chinese. Few white anglos convert to Buddhism with the exception of secular atheists. And those vietnamese, korean, and chinese sanghas are actually very progressive in their open-mindedness because they originate from different communities within their own countries. I considered this when asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

Buddhism is a discipline with a clearly defined principles about what it considers to be the truths or realities related to the arising & ceasing of suffering. Therefore, the question about "narrow-mindedness" is illogical or irrelevant.

For example, Buddhism teaches suffering arises due to ignorance, craving, attachment & egoism and this truth of causal arising is held to be absolutely true & unchangeable in Buddhism.

Or, on a moral level, Buddhism teaches about actions that lead to harm. These actions that lead to harm can never ever be changed.

Like any authentic science, Buddhism is about accurate, specific & narrow principles of causation.

The Dhammapada states:

> *273. Of all the paths the Eightfold Path is the best; of all the truths the Four Noble Truths are the best; of all things
>   passionlessness is the best: of men the Seeing One (the Buddha) is the
>   best.*
>
> *274. **This is the only path**; there is none other for the purification of insight. Tread this path, and you will bewilder Mara.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68288/discussion-on-answer-by-dhammadhatu-is-it-common-for-buddhists-in-eastern-countr).

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of the object, of the food, but at it's root, if observing well, there is no different. Views, either greedy, aversive or defuse appearing are views.

And for politics increasing greed and pleasure is more conductive. One can say that it is like controling the markted of drugs. Sometimes east did it, sometimes west. Currently Asia has it under control, made it their tool.

When ever on hears that people of certain geografic or birth are inherent different, one can be sure that the observant is/was not very attentive and took either this world and views or that as real.

Wordlings from Buddhist Countries are interested in the marked like popular Western teachers. An all tolerating, all serving business bring fast costumers, since the mass is not very smart but greedy and full of conceit.

Since many eastern still learn service and devotion as a tool from child on, they have it generally easier in this regard, but on the other hand, those rejecting service and devotion are fastly winning people in the east. So so called "open-minded" comes generaly for a certain purpose and was always a good tool acting smart to again just win.

So no hope for refuge in regard of realm of certain birth, because their conditions change as well by time, better by deeds.

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for commercial purpose or other low wordily gains by means of trade and exchange.]*